# Display arrray of strings in same TextView with a time interval of 5 seconds

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am working on android application to retrieving JSON data from url and display it.

My Requirement:-
 I have array of JSON data and i have to display each array item data every 5 seconds once, and once executed all array items, it should call onpostexecute again as usual it should start from first array

```
  private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            arraylist = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONObject jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);

            try {

                String link = jsonobject.getString("link");
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("api");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = jsonobject.getString("Title");
                    String subtitle = jsonobject.getString("Subtitle");
                    String image = jsonobject.getString("image");

                    map.put("title",jsonobject.getString("Title"));
                    map.put("sub",jsonobject.getString("Subtitle"));
                    map.put("image",link+jsonobject.getString("image"));

                    arraylist.add(map);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


            for (int i=0; i<arraylist.size();i++){
                final String tit =   arraylist.get(i).get("title");
                final String subtit =   arraylist.get(i).get("sub");
                String img =   arraylist.get(i).get("image");

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       while (true){
                           try{

                               Thread.sleep(5000);
                               mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                         t1.setText(tit);//t1,t2 is textview
                                         t2.setText(subtit);
                                   }
                               });

                           }catch (Exception e){

                           }
                       }

                    }
                }).start();

            }
        }
    }
```

Actually This above code is partially working which means first time it working but after 5 seconds  it is refreshing but data is not updating after some time data is changing i am not understanding how it is working, as mentioned my requirement it should execute each item in every 5 seconds once and it should restart onpostexecute after item execution completed then after that as usual and so on

Comment: t1.setText(tit);//t1,t2 is textview
                                         t2.setText(subtit); will be executed only once after 5seconds from when onPostExecute is called.. You need to setup Alarm manager to initiate asynctask every 5seconds

Comment: There are lot of things just wrong like you are creating a thread in a for loop and many more. Please review your code. I suggest use Alarm Manager or simply a timertask.

Comment: @Dhina you mean i have to use alarm manager instead of handler?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i am using handler only, could you please tell me how exactly we have to use handler in m y requirement

Comment: @Dhina i don't  want to initiate whole asyntask i want to initiate only onpostexecute because already i am getting from url and store it into arraylist i want to excute each and every item from arraylist should come 5 seconds ones

Comment: after get your json array, you should better use TimerTask than Thread

Comment: @LinhNguyen you mean i have to use timer task intsead of thread? if yes how can i use timer task inside for loop, is it possible?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if works pls

Comment: @rizwan " The TimerTask class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly." you can see the sample here : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

declare these globally:

```
private TimerTask NoticeTimerTask;
  private final Handler handler = new Handler();
  Timer timer = new Timer();
```

call the function from onPostExecute()

```
        setViews(arraylist);
```

setViews()

```
 private void setViews(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        final int max = arraylist.size();
        final int[] current = {0};
        NoticeTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(current[0] <max) {
                            Log.d("NoticeTimerTask", String.valueOf(current[0]));
                            t1.setText(arraylist.get(current[0]).get("title"));
                            t2.setText(arraylist.get(current[0]).get("sub"));
                            current[0]++;
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d("NoticeTimerTask", String.valueOf(current[0]) + " timer.cancel();");
                           // current[0] = 0; // do this if yu want to loop back from first item
                            timer.cancel(); // do this if you want to stop
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        if (timer!=null) {
            timer.schedule(NoticeTimerTask, 0, 5000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ya it is working fine but if i give onclick listner for t1 like                                 
`public void onClick(View v) { String str= arraylist.get(current[0]).get("title");                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+arraylist.get(current[0]).get("title"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`
     i have three 3 items in my arraylist if i click 1st item  toast is displaying for 2nd and if i click 2nd toast is displaying for third , can you tell me how to get correct position

Comment: may be by the time toast is initiated 5seconds would have passed hence the next item is fetched?

Comment: try increasing the timervalue and check if that is the exact reason.

Comment: I have increased timer value from 5000 to 10000, i am getting same problem, already i said i have three items in my arraylist. if i click first, second is displaying and if click second third is displaying, if click third, index out of bound exception

Comment: it is perfect for me.. `t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });`

Comment: I get it now you are getting from arraylist which is wrong because as soon as you click the textview the position is changed to next index. You should get from the textview as above comment.

Comment: actually you are getting text from textview and display it but why i am asking here toast means i have one more data  in my Json called link if i click first item it should redirect to first item link and if click second item it should redirect to second item link for that purpose only here i am trying to get position like arraylist.get(current[0]).get("link")

Comment: simple save the current[0] to a temp before incrementing and use temp as the index

Comment: It is working perfect Thank you so much and thank you for your quick response and please continue your help for freshers like us and once again thank you so much for all

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create new TimerTask for every loop, just schedule the timer  for 5s , get and update the value on the run method of TimerTask

```
//declare index variable
private int index =0;
```

// on your postExecute method call this :

```
timer = new Timer();

timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {



            //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                final String tit =   arraylist.get(index).get("title");
                final String subtit =   arraylist.get(index).get("sub");
                String img =   arraylist.get(index).get("image");
                t1.setText(tit);//t1,t2 is textview
                t2.setText(subtit);
               index ++;

                }

            });

        }

    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000); //
```