# android update textview for every 30 seconds

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time, textview

I want to start a timer from `0th` second and for every 30 seconds,

**I need to update the textview as `0.5min, 1.0min, 1.5min` etc**.

How do I do this?

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261910/display-arrray-of-strings-in-same-textview-with-a-time-interval-of-5-seconds/34263567#34263567 may be use this as base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
  final Handler h = new Handler();
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    long millis = (long) currentTime();

                    dateAndTime.setText(getDate(millis, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));

                    h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
```

Comment: How do i get my incremented values for the textview?

Comment: what do you mean by increamented value in textview ?

Comment: I mean in your code inside run(), what value should I assign to my tetxview so that it displays the incremented value like 0.5min,1.0min etc

Comment: check updated answer@Samuel909

Answer (score 0):

We can use an `handler` to handle that.

You can define as below

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // write your code update textview

        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 30000);
        return true;

    }
})
```

This handler will auto send and update the text again. You also need insert your code to update time for TextView.

Don't forget call the handler in the first time: `mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`